# What are the elements of the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$ generated by 7?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Can someone please explain in detail? Do I need to find a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ that is all the multiples of 7?

Comment: Are any of the *multiples* of $7$ the multiplicative inverse, $1/7$?

Comment: The set of multiples of $7$ is an *additive* subgroup, and it's not contained in $\mathbf R^*$ since it contains $0$.

Comment: No, good point.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a\in\Bbb R^*$,
$$\langle a\rangle=\{a^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

Comment: So a=7 in this case?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You may have noticed this group is isomorphic to the integers...thus, logarithms! (this conversion of sums to products, and vice-versa underpins the importance of exponential maps and logarithms, the homomorphisms most people know of, but don't realize that's what they are).

Comment: Is there a general rule like this for complex numbers? Like if I was looking at a subgroup generated by i?

Comment: @user104203 Yes, the same idea will work for $i$ in $\Bbb C^*$.  Although, $\langle i\rangle$ is a finite group.

Comment: Hmm...so the real line would get mapped to something that repeats over and over, like, what- a circle?

Comment: @DavidWheeler Hmm.  Not sure what map you are talking about.

Comment: Maybe, $t \mapsto e^{it}$. Yeah, I think that's it.

Comment: @DavidWheeler  Yes, that map will take the real line  to the unit circle.